# Initial state Redux store - invalid prop

Tags: reactjs, redux

After arguing a lot with my coworkers about the initial state value for async data fetched via the API, we decided that it would be more clear to have initial values set as empty array / empty object instead of null.

But when I implemented it today I realized that an empty object would throw a 'PropTypes warning' even if the prop is not required since it is not null.

Is it a bad practice to set the initial value to empty object inside the state ? Or is there a way not to get the warning ?

my current initial state looks like :

```
    const user = (state = {
      isRetrieving: false,
      isUpdating: false,
      hasRetrieved: false,
      didInvalidate: false,
      item: {},
    }, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };
```

Comment: You mean your validation failed? What does that look like?

Comment: Could you add your PropTypes to the questions?

Answer (score 0):

if anything is required in your app state, you should make it part of the initial state, starting always with an empty object will make you add defensive code all over your components (you'd be making every component handle undefined properties, when that's not a useful state to support).

to make it simpler, I would think this question as similar to "should I make my class constructor without arguments?", the problem is analogous, if the object always requires a certain argument, make it a constructor argument, make it part of the initial state, don't support extra states that are not needed as that has a cost in complexity.

So, no, don't make your initial state an empty object (neither null) as it will make your components a bit more complicated, although I don't think that's officially considered a bad redux practice.

Finally, beware that redux state is not the same as component props, if something is actually a default value for a component prop (and not something required for the app state), you can use `Component.defaultProps`, `defaultProps` is a static member of a React component with values that are set by default for your `Component.propTypes`, or you can even return this default props from a function,
see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#default-prop-values